# how to exit a bash script running tcpdump with error data

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, exit, tcpdump

I have the following bash script that takes tcpdump data and pipes it (eventually) to mysql to be written to a database. In case the script crashes, cron runs with piped output once a minute to check for the tcpdump process and restart it if necessary.

```
bash /usr/bin/uem_trap >>/var/log/uem.log 2>&1
```

The script does crash from time to time with various errors and I'd like to get more verbose information when it does so that I can improve the script.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1665: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,"",");
```

Linux host.domain.com 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 21 11:57:15 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Maria DB version: 10.2.40-MariaDB

```
#!/bin/sh

if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep '/usr/sbin/tcpdump -l -i ens192 -n -nn port snmptrap' ; then
    exit 0
else
    /usr/sbin/tcpdump -l -i ens192 -n -nn port snmptrap | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -F '( IP 1| +\\.1.3.6.1.([0-9]|\\.)+=)' '{gsub(/(^\"|\"$)/,"",$15); gsub(/\"/,"|",$15); gsub(/(^|$)/,"\"",$15); print "use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES (\"" $1 "\","  $3 "," $16 "," $7 "," $9 "," $10 "," $11 ",\"" $13 "\"," $15 ");\n"}' | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 mysql --user=uuuu --password=pppp &
fi
```

per request, a few lines of tcpdump:

```
09:49:15.914587 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.162:  F= U="MotoNorth" E=_80_00_00_a1_03_00_0c_29_5e_74_32 C="" V2Trap(448)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=568989040 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.104.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.3.0=55420744 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.4.0="PortStatusClear" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.5.0=4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.6.0="10.201.8.240:port:16" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.7.0="16" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.8.0="cs01l008s1.convloc8.csub1.ucs" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.9.0=6 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.10.0="10.201.8.240:HpSwitch2620-24" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.11.0=07_e6_06_0a_09_31_0f_08_2d_05_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.12.0=07_b2_01_01_00_00_00_00_2b_00_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.13.0="Port state is UP" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.19.0=7901418 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.20.0="10.201.8.240"
09:49:15.915396 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.162:  F= U="MotoNorth" E=_80_00_00_a1_03_00_0c_29_5e_74_32 C="" V2Trap(536)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=568989040 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.104.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.3.0=55420745 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.4.0=".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.129.0.2" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.5.0=256 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.6.0="10.201.8.240" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.7.0="10.201.8.240" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.8.0="cs01l008s1.convloc8.csub1.ucs" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.9.0=7 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.10.0="10.201.8.240:HpSwitch2620-24" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.11.0=07_e6_06_0a_09_31_0f_08_2d_05_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.12.0=07_b2_01_01_00_00_00_00_2b_00_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.13.0="HP Networking 2620-24 Trap - I 06/10/22 14:49:12 00076 ports: port 16 is now on-line" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.19.0=7901419 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.20.0="10.201.8.240"
09:49:17.938223 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.162:  F= U="MotoNorth" E=_80_00_00_a1_03_00_0c_29_5e_74_32 C="" V2Trap(493)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=568989243 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.104.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.3.0=55420746 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.4.0="zc_trunked_site_channel.1.1" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.5.0=11 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.6.0="MZC-1:zc_trunked_site_channel:60.4" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.7.0="Trunked Site Channel 4" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.8.0="Site 60 at zone1" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.9.0=6 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.10.0="MZC-1:ZCcallProcessingSubsystemSite:60" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.11.0=07_e6_06_0a_09_31_11_09_2d_05_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.12.0=07_e6_06_0a_09_31_11_00_2d_05_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.13.0="ENABLED, NO REASON" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.19.0=7901420 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.20.0="10.1.233.100"
09:49:22.886594 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.162:  F= U="MotoNorth" E=_80_00_00_a1_03_00_0c_29_5e_74_32 C="" V2Trap(644)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=568989738 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.104.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.3.0=55420747 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.4.0=".1.3.6.1.2.1.14.16.2.10.1" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.5.0=256 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.6.0="10.1.253.202" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.7.0="10.1.253.202" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.8.0="z001edge02.zone1" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.9.0=7 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.10.0="10.1.253.202:FMT_juniper-1500" .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.11.0=07_e6_06_0a_09_31_16_08_2d_05_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.12.0=07_b2_01_01_00_00_00_00_2b_00_00 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.13.0="OSPF packet has been retransmitted on a non- virtual interface. All packets that may be re- transmitted are associated with an LSDB entry. The LS type, LS ID, and Router ID are used to identify the LSDB entry." .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.19.0=7901421 .1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.10.105.20.0="10.1.253.202"
```

UPDATE 6/10 14:27: I discovered that every now and then I get these when one device sends a few traps with a large message:

```
10:26:14.969355 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.snmptrap:  [len1468<asnlen2143]
10:26:14.970131 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.snmptrap:  [len1468<asnlen2042]
10:26:15.179580 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.snmptrap:  [len1468<asnlen2225]
10:26:15.290469 IP 192.168.11.20.60751 > 10.74.251.198.snmptrap:  [len1468<asnlen2338]
```

I have increased the capture size to 2500. We'll watch and see what happens.

```
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 2500 -l -i ens192 -n -nn port snmptrap...
```

Comment: post a sample of 2 or 3 lines of tcpdump output so others can test the script.

Comment: posted above...

Answer (score 0):

Seems there's a problem with quoting inside `awk`script.
Testing with a static string that simulates a `snmptrap`:

```
read -r -d '' snmpstr <<'EOFS'
11:47:50.905818 IP 10.10.201.27.56503 > 10.10.202.11.162:  V2Trap(138)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=791308 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1=1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1="FastEthernet0/0" .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1=6 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.20.1="up"
10:59:17.614465 IP 10.25.5.20.43471 > 10.25.5.30.snmptrap:  V2Trap(185)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=155084 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.7 .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.2="CentOS" .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.6="Users" .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.7=1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.17="USERS WARNING - 1 users currently logged in"
EOFS
 
    echo "$snmpstr" | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -F '( IP 1| +\\.1.3.6.1.([0-9]|\\.)+=)' '{gsub(/(^\"|\"$)/,"",$15); gsub(/\"/,"|",$15); gsub(/(^|$)/,"\"",$15); print "use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES (\"" $1 "\","  $3 "," $16 "," $7 "," $9 "," $10 "," $11 ",\"" $13 "\"," $15 ");\n" }'
```

Result similar to OP's SQL reported error due to missing fields in input

```
use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES ("11:47:50.905818",791308,,6,,,,"",");

use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES ("10:59:17.614465",155084,,1,,,,"",");
```

Now if SQL query is moved to an external variable with `printf` formatters, it works better and code is more readable. Testing with all fields present

```
read -r -d '' snmpstr <<'EOFS'
11:47:50.905818 IP 10.10.201.27.56503 > 10.10.202.11.162:  V2Trap(138)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=791308 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1=1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1="FastEthernet0/0" .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.1=777 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.2.1.1.20.1="up" .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=999 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=101010 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=111111 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=121212 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=field13 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=141414 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=151515 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=161616
10:59:17.614465 IP 10.25.5.20.43471 > 10.25.5.30.snmptrap:  V2Trap(185)  .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=155084 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0=.1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.7 .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.2="CentOS" .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.6="Users" .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.7=777 .1.3.6.1.4.1.20006.1.3.1.17="USERS WARNING - 1 users currently logged in" .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=999 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=101010 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=111111 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=121212 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=field13 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=141414 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=151515 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0=161616
EOFS

sql='use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES ("%s",%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,"%s",%s);\n'
echo "$snmpstr" | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 awk -v sql="$sql" -F '( IP 1| +\\.1.3.6.1.([0-9]|\\.)+=)' '{gsub(/(^\"|\"$)/,"",$15); gsub(/\"/,"|",$15); gsub(/(^|$)/,"\"",$15); printf sql,$1,$3,$16,$7,$9,$10,$11,$13, $15 }'

# uncomment this line to print debug found fields
#echo "$snmpstr" | awk -v sql="$sql" -F '( IP 1| +\\.1.3.6.1.([0-9]|\\.)+=)' 'BEGIN{OFS=" ¬ "} {gsub(/(^\"|\"$)/,"",$15); gsub(/\"/,"|",$15); gsub(/(^|$)/,"\"",$15); print "1:" $1, "3:" $3, "16:" $16, "7:" $7, "9:" $9, "10:" $10, "11:" $11, "13:" $13, "15:" $15 }'
```

Result

```
use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES ("11:47:50.905818",791308,161616,777,999,101010,111111,"field13","151515");
use uem; INSERT INTO uem_log (uem_dt, uem_num, uem_seq, category, entity, resource, severity, detect_time, message) VALUES ("10:59:17.614465",155084,161616,777,999,101010,111111,"field13","151515");
```

Incomplete records could be avoided by checking the number of `awk`
records

```
if(NF >= 16){ printf sql,$1,$3,$16,$7,$9,$10,$11,$13,$15 } else { print "Incomplete snmptrap record: " $0 > "/dev/stderr" }
```

Comment: this script successfully processes up to 100 of lines per minute of tcpdump on a regular basis, with the occasional (a few times a day) failure. I'm thinking that probably some snmp trap comes in that is not formatted as expected, perhaps from an unaccounted for source. I like the idea of simply checking for incomplete records and dumping the errant source string in order to help determine the issue and make adjustments.

Comment: Seems that fields 9, 10 are strings not integers so it should be `VALUES ("%s",%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%d,"%s",%s)`